# Had Andrew a little patient... - error in the example sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

At https://www.learngrammar.net/a/examples-of-inversion-used-in-conditional-sentences there's one example which I think has an error in it. Specifically

**Had Andrew a little patient, he could have done the task.**

I think I understand how "Have Andrew had a little..." collapses to "Had Andrew a little...". But "patient"? Shouldn't it be "patience"?

Comment: Yes, it should be patience. Do not trust that site.

Comment: Some of the examples there are laughably wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some very unusual circumstances, the text as given would make sense, but the obvious meaning requires the word "patience."

You are also correct about wondering about the syntax. What was meant is virtually certain to be

> Had Andrew had a little patience, he could have finished the task.

Comment: Quite so. The right context can change the meaning of the sentence. *Andrew, the doctor, lost his stethoscope under his desk. But his patient, like him, was too large to retrieve it.* ***Had Andrew a little patient, he could have done the task.*** This is a highly unusual interpretation, but not wrong if considered in the right context.